AWS glue not conection
it is issue
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.getJDBCSink.
: com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.EntityNotFoundException: Connection not found (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityNotFoundException; Request ID: 74cc04cb-a815-4b4f-9afc-f4f75570bbfb; Proxy: null)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.doInvoke(AWSGlueClient.java:15096)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.invoke(AWSGlueClient.java:15063)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.invoke(AWSGlueClient.java:15052)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.executeGetConnection(AWSGlueClient.java:5493)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.AWSGlueClient.getConnection(AWSGlueClient.java:5463)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.$anonfun$getConnection$1(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:379)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.getConnection(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:375)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.$anonfun$getJDBCConf$1(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:225)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.getJDBCConf(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:224)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getJDBCSink(GlueContext.scala:728)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getJDBCSink(GlueContext.scala:716)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
i try to test conection and reset but it not good

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
